# Can I use word exceptionally to mark a case of missing exceptions?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Can word "exceptionally" be used as:

1. "as an exception" - e.g. *However, taking their popularity into account, they were exceptionally allowed in.*
2. "without any exceptions" - e.g. *Children in this family enter exceptionally State Taxation Academy.*

I always thought option 1 is the only valid, but today I saw option 2 in Google Translate output, hence this question.

Comment: Don’t think Google Translate is any indication of grammaticality.  That sentence is nonsense.  And for number 1. It’s not idiomatic at a minimum.  “... taking their popularity into account, an exception was made to let them in.”  sounds much better to me. The only time I use ***exceptionally*** is To modify adjectives:  exceptionally gifted, exceptionally poor, etc.

Comment: children enter the state taxation academy? What a nightmare....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at a reputable dictionary definition for [**exceptionally**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exceptionally):

> **1.1** Only in unusual circumstances.
>
> ‘the court allows half an hour in most cases, one hour exceptionally for a very important case’
>
> ‘He called upon the educationists to join hands for formulating a strategy that benefits all rather than exceptionally a few.’
>
> ‘Scores lower than 4 were found only exceptionally.’
>
> ‘Exceptionally, international institutions perform functions more appropriately described as international resource management.’
>
> ‘Reproductions made by professional photographers can only be authorised exceptionally.’
>
> ‘However, exceptionally, Parliament has affected the validity of a contract by intervening to refuse funding.’

Although not common, it's perfectly grammatical to use this sense of the word.

But for your second example sentence to be okay, it would need to be rephrased:

> Children in this family enter the State Taxation Academy exceptionally.

However, doing so would change it's meaning from "without any exceptions." To retain that meaning, it needs to be something like:

> Without exception, children are not allowed to enter the State Taxation Academy.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of these are correct, as far as I am aware.

The adverb "exceptionally" can either mean, "to an unusual degree", as with

> "This summer has been *exceptionally* hot,"

or it can also mean "occurring only in unusual circumstances," as with

> "This pool will remain open for the entire week, closing *exceptionally* for inclement weather."

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exceptionally)

Google Translate is not a good standard for grammar, *especially* for non-Romantic languages, so take the options it gives with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Funny enough, your 2nd example highlights a usage quite similar to my 1st example - "as an exception". Regarding the example #1 in my question not being correct - well, that's my English level, sorry :) Most importantly, the usage pattern is there, so thanks!

Comment: @MikeMakarov I was scratching my head at that one, too. I *think* (but don't quote me) the difference is that the example I give is speculative about the future, while the one you gave talks about the past.

Comment: Where's the reference for the second example?  This sounds to me like something written by a non-native speaker--or someone trying to sound sophisticated who should have used "occasionally" instead.

Comment: @Xanne It's from the Oxford English Dictionary, so, unless that was written by a pretentious "non-native" speaker... https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exceptionally

Comment: @SeraphsWrath Indeed it is--I missed that when I read your post.  Still, a register with a certain degree of hautiness, of putting on airs.